# API Callback_URL Invalid Calls

Tags: android, web-services, callback, oauth-2.0

I just started working with the Strava API on Android. In order to use it, I first need to successfully set up OAuth2. For this, I chose to use the Scribe library, since I have used it in a previous implementation.

Authentication happens in onCreate() method of the MainActivity. The test application uses two classes next to the MainActivity. StravaOAuth20ServiceImpl is for configuring the API requests for token and revoking of the token. StravaOAuth2Api contains the EndPoints for the API. These look ok.

I am not getting a code back from the callback. That's where I am stuck. In order to function, the callback needs to be set up correctly in Developer Settings for Strava, Android Manifest and the API EndPoint call.

I am currently working in Development Mode.. On the website it is stated that "`localhost` and `127.0.0.1` are white-listed", so I have used these in my callback_url. For both I get the following JSON as a response:

```
{
"message": "Bad Request",
"errors": [
{
"resource": "Application",
"field": "redirect_uri",
"code": "invalid"
}
]
}
```

So both these calls are invalid..

```
- https://www.strava.com/oauth/authorize?response_type=code&client_id=25016&redirect_uri=127.0.0.1

- https://www.strava.com/oauth/authorize?response_type=code&client_id=25016&redirect_uri=localhost
```

A related Question is about the form of the callback_url. I have done the same for FitBit and have used a callback in the form "http://callback_myapplication". In order to do so, I have to set up a "host" and "scheme" in my Android Manifest (see code underneath). When I try to do so in my application settings, I get an error message "Field has to be a domain, without //" (see print screen underneath). This is the first time I see this. Is it the callback without "scheme" then?

```
<activity android:name=".MainActivity">
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW"/>
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT"/>
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE"/>
        <data android:host="127.0.0.1"
            android:scheme="http"/>
    </intent-filter>
```

[image]

Thank you on beforehand for your help!

Answer (score 2):

Strava's official documentation is here:
https://developers.strava.com/docs/authentication/

According to their documentation, localhost and 127.0.0.1 are both whitelisted. So the redirect should work to localhost regardless of the setting on the application page. That has been my experience as well: redirecting to any port of localhost should just work.

When it comes time to set-up a real URL, the callback domain setting should be just the domain name. No protocol (e.g. http/https), no port number. So for example, simply "myapp.domain.com".

Answer (score -1):

following the [OAuth2 documentation](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6749#section-4.1.3), you must use exactly the same value that you have included in your authorization settings.

Therefore in your case *redirect_uri* param should be:

```
http://127.0.0.1
```

Best!

Comment: This is still not working.. My full code can be found on "https://github.com/NVwingh84/StravaAPITest", if you would have the time to check would be great..

Comment: This isn't true in my experience with Strava. The web UI will actually give an error if you try including "http". It will say "This field must be just a domain, no slashes or paths." If you include a port number, it won't generate an error in the UI, but it will cause the redirect to throw an error. So in the end, it should ONLY be the domain name.